Reuse okhttp client but change proxy auth every request
I have a Spring Boot application using a Feign client with an OkHttp client configuration. Currently, I’m creating a new OkHttpClient instance for each request to set a different proxy authentication username.
Here’s the FeignClient interface:
@FeignClient(name = "location", value = "location", url = "https://ip.oxylabs.io", configuration = CustomConfiguration.class)
public interface LocationClient {
    @GetMapping("/location")
    LocationResponse getIp();
}

The configuration class looks like this:
public class CustomConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Client customClient() {
        return new DynamicProxyFeignClient();
    }
}

The DynamicProxyFeignClient class is implemented as follows:
public class DynamicProxyFeignClient extends Client.Default {
    private OkHttpClient client;

    public DynamicProxyFeignClient() {
        super(null, null);
        this.client = buildClient();
    }

    private OkHttpClient buildClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT)))
                .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(500, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public Response execute(Request request, Request.Options options) throws IOException {
        client = client.newBuilder()
                .proxyAuthenticator((route, response) -> {
                    String credential = Credentials.basic(generateUsername(), PROXY_PASSWORD);
                    return response.request().newBuilder()
                            .header("Proxy-Authorization", credential)
                            .build();
                })
                .build();
        return new feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient(client).execute(request, options);
    }

}

I need to change the session ID for the residential proxy to rotate the IP address with each request. However, I’m facing connection issues under heavy load when making numerous asynchronous requests, leading to SocketTimeoutException. Monitoring the system’s socket usage reveals that new connections are being created for each request.
Even if I try to manage proxy rotation on the proxy provider’s side, it recognizes that the connection remains the same, causing it to use the same proxy for multiple requests. I need a new IP for each request, which necessitates changing the session ID or establishing a new connection.
I attempted to modify the Proxy-Authorization header using a RequestInterceptor, but this did not resolve the issue, resulting in a “proxy authorization required” error. It seems the header is being set on the final request rather than the proxy request.
How can I refactor my configuration to reuse the OkHttp client while still changing the proxy authorization?
